# How do you correctly specify a filter to get all orders that have been updated since date

Tags: magento2, filter, rest-api

I have tried to create a filter to get all updated orders since date...

```
rest/V1/orders/searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-01-01T14:01:54.9571247Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt
```

I got the following error

```
{
    "message": "Invalid type for value: \"searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-01-01T14:01:54.9571247Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt\". Expected Type: \"int\".",
    "trace": null }
```

I read this as ... can't use a date with a gt condition. How do I get the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-01-01T14:01:54.9571247Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt
```